# Deeply nested data objects in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I've got a VueJs front end that fetches some data from an API.  The app uses vue-router.

The data fetched for one component is similar to the following:

```
{
  name: ...,
  email: ...,
  order: {
    data: {
      line_items: [
        {
          quantity: ...
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The component is instantiated with a data object called info:

```
data () {
  return {
    info: {}
  }
}
```

In the `beforeRouteEnter` hook, the data is fetched by a vue-resource http.get and  info is set to the body of the result like this:

```
vm.info = result.body
```

When the component renders, the following errors are produced:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating _vm.order.data.line_items')`

In the template, the data is referenced in curly braces as per usual, however, if I just reference info in the template like this:

`{{ info }}`

it will output all of the data and not complain at all.

What is the correct way to assign a deeply nested data object?

Comment: I don't think you can do this in `beforeRouteEnter` hook. As it's said in [the doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#incomponent-guards), `does NOT have access to `this` component instance`. How about changing the hook to `created`?

Comment: @kxxoling Typo. The object is set in a callback in the beforeEnterRoute function. I've edited the post.

Comment: Have you tried to use the hook to `created` instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you are finding @saurabh answer is not working then you may need to check how you are assigning the new values to your object.

Firstly is the data being accidiently set as a string? hence {{ info }} working (or appearing to). May be worth using `response.json()` to set the data.

If thats not it then the error may be produced as the data you have set is not reactive. As you are assigning a nested object you may need to use different methods to make it reactive, i.e

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

or

```
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

check out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

because your response is an object you may want to break out your data into corresponding params, i.e.

```
data () {
  return {
    info: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      order: {},
    },
  }
}
```

then you can assign name & email as you expected (info.email = ...).

For `info.order` you'd use `Vue.set`:

```
Vue.set(this.info, 'order', result.body.order)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [condition rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) here, which you can easily do with help of Vue directive v-if. It may give error if the data is not populated and you try to access it, so `v-if` will render that part of HTML only when data is present.

You need to do something like following:

```
<div v-if="info.order">
  <span>
    {{ info.order }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've actually tried that.  It stills throws the same errors when evaluating the properties that aren't available.

Comment: @oorst can you include your HTML.

Comment: @oorst did you forget to convert the response body string to js objects with `res.json()` (vue-resource api) or `JSON.parse(res.body)`?

Comment: Doesn't vue resource automatically return JS objects?

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I had to use one `Vue.set` that wrapped an `Object.assign`:

I'm trying to set `state.workouts[state.workoutDate].isDone` in a [Vuex mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

```js
    toggleWorkout(state, isDone) {
        Vue.set(
            state.workouts,
            state.workoutDate,
            Object.assign({}, state.workouts[state.workoutDate], { isDone: isDone })
        );
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue here is a life cycle one. The route guard `beforeRouteEnter` is called after the component is created so the error is thrown because the data isn’t there when the component tries to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Force update object setting a new object with same content

```
<button @click="my.object.nested.variable = 2; my = Object.assign({}, my);">
```

or

```
this.my.object.nested.variable = 2;
this.my = Object.assign({}, this.my);
```